# Blender crashes/refuses to run on my two machines

Tags: error

**Computer 1:**

My [CPU](https://www.cnet.com/products/intel-celeron-g460-1-8-ghz-processor-qy835av/),
specs of my [card](https://www.cnet.com/products/diamond-ati-radeon-hd-5450-). Graphics-card-Radeon-hd-5450-1-Gb/
Memory: 4 Gigs, DDR3.
OS: Windows 7.
[I am not that knowledgeable with computers, so please inform me if I am leaving out any important information.]

**[Computer 2](https://www.91mobiles.com/toshiba-c55-a5302-pentium-dual-core-6-gb-500-gb-windows-8-laptop-price-in-india-62215):**

I should note that it is currently on Windows 8.1.
In both of them I tried running blender but it crashes.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: For the first computer, make sure the graphics drivers are up to date. For the second, I can't tell because the graphics specifications are not detailed enough and I am unsure about the processor.

Comment: I just checked and the driver is updated.
I will look into getting more detailed information on the 2nd computer.

Comment: Computer 2 CPU: Intel Pentium CPU 2020M @ 2.4GHz

Comment: Computer 2 graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4.0.0